# NodeJs: Compare URL Parameters & Delete Requests with array values using Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, body-parser

So, I have these Express routes for an array of objects, and made some CRUD operations, but I'm stuck at the "Delete" one.

I want to delete an object by grabbing it's url parameter ID and check if it matches with the value of it's key. Everything seem to work except 2 things:

- The "text" key can be anything(doesn't matter if it's not in the array).
- The url ID doesn't need to match it's own "text" as long as it matches an existing one.

I know I'm missing some parameters, but after googling for a while and trying a few different things, I can't seem to put my finger on it. I'm new to programming and probably explained it badly, but bear with me please.

*app.js*

```
    var foodList = [
      {
       id:'e3ed4we23',
       text:'honey'
      },
      {
       id:'12312oi3i2',
       text:'milk'
      },
      {
       id:'1023u2kodw',
       text:'chicken'
      },
      {
       id:'213021381203',
       text:'eggs'
      }
    ];

    app.delete('/food-list/delete/:ingredientId', function(req, res) {
       var removeIngredient = req.body.text;
       if(!removeIngredient || removeIngredient.length == 0) {
         console.log('Cannot remove this ingredient:', removeIngredient);
         res.status(500).send({error:'Cannot remove invalid ingredient text'});

      }else {
         var idFound = false;
         for(var index = 0; index < foodList.length; index++) {
             var foundIngredient = foodList[index];
             if(foundIngredient.id == req.params.ingredientId) {
                 console.log('Removed ingredient: ',  foundIngredient.text); 
                 foundIngredient.text = removeIngredient;
                 foodList.splice(index, 1);
                 idFound = true;
                 break;
             }
         }
          if(!idFound) {
             res.status(500).send({error:'The ID you selected is invalid, please try again'});

          }else {
             res.status(200).send(foodList); 
          }

        }
    });
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: I'm not getting any error, it deletes the item, but for example if I'm on localhost:3001/food-list/delete/e3ed4we23 which is the ''honey" id, I can type  in  the "text" : "anything" and it will delete the object because the id is valid.  I wanted the "text"  to match it's id if that makes any sense.

Comment: you don't want to delete it just based on its id? you want to delete only if its text sent through body matches?

Comment: Yes. The id should match the body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to delete the object based on both `text` and `used_id` then you need to use this:

```
for(var index = 0; index < foodList.length; index++) {
             var foundIngredient = foodList[index];
             if(foundIngredient.id == req.params.ingredientId && foundIngredient.text == removeIngredient ) {
                 console.log('Removed ingredient: ',  foundIngredient.text); 
                 foodList.splice(index, 1);
                 idFound = true;
                 break;
             }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that worked like a charm, I knew it was something like this but didn't knew exactly, thank you man.

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused as to why you are bothering with the request body at all. All you need to delete the item is its id, which you get in the url parameter. I'm also not clear on what the error you are seeing is. From a quick glance, I think your code will run fine, though it is a little overcomplicated.

You could write the same route like this:

```
app.delete('/food-list/delete/:ingredientId', function(req, res) {
  var removedIndex = foodList.findIndex(function(ingredient) {
    return ingredient.id === req.params.ingredientId;
  })

  if (removedIndex === -1) {
    res.status(500).send({error:'The ID you selected is invalid, please try again'});
  } else {
    foodList.splice(removedIndex, 1);
    console.log('Removed ingredient:', foodList[removedIndex].text);
    res.status(200).send(foodList); 
  }
});
```

Comment: This is more elegant solution for what I wrote, but it does  the same thing.

Comment: Yes, that is roughly what I said. It is not clear to me what else you are trying to do. Deleting by id is typical REST API behavior.